# не работает background с url

Tags: html

не работает свойство background если в него прописать url() вот код

```
<div class="bx-footer-section py-5 bg-white">
            <div style="background:url (images/left.png)  url(images/right.png) 100%">
</div>
```

Comment: сразу говорю, что перед путем я ставил ../ , но это не помогло

Comment: Скорее всего нужно настроить ширину и высоту вашего дива с задним фоном.

Answer (score -1):

```
<style>
body { 
  background: lightblue url("img_tree.gif") no-repeat fixed center; 
}
</style>
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]